# Last element in group omitting NA -

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am looking for a way to get last element in group omitting NA. Standard dplyr solution is not working and it is not clear when it is going to be fixed [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2090)

Can anybody suggest work around?

Here is an example of what I am looking for

```
df <- DataFrame(col_1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), col_2 = c(1, NA, 3, 3))
```

So I would like to group by col_1 and for group A return 1 and for group B return 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `na.omit` and `tail`:

```
df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(last=tail(na.omit(col_2),1))

   col_1  last
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      A     1
2      B     3
```

Or you could `filter` your dataframe, then `slice` the last row per group:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(col_2)) %>% group_by(col_1) %>% slice(n())
```

Comment: Thank you! It is funny how `last(na.omit(col_2))` and `col_2[!is.na(col_2)]` do not work, but `tail` does!

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'col_1', `arrange` using the logical vector `is.na(col_2)` and `slice` the first element

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(col_1)%>% 
  arrange(is.na(col_2)) %>%
  slice(1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   col_1 [2]
#    col_1 col_2 
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      A     1
#2      B     3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `arrange(is.na(col_2))` is very new to me. I poorly stated my question. I need last not-NA element in each group. Lamia already answered the question, but thank you for great example!